Why this ILP and LP are equivalent?
Let's consider a competition with $n$ questions. Each question has a price $p_i$ and a score $v_i$. To advance to the next round of the competition, we need to accumulate a minimum score of $D$. We can purchase a question, answer it, and earn its score. Assuming we can answer any question we buy, which subset of questions should we select to achieve a minimum score of $D$ while minimizing the total cost of the questions?
This problem can be formulated as an integer linear programming problem:
$$\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\text{minimize } \quad & \sum_{i=1}^n p_ix_i \\
\text{subject to }\quad &
\begin{array}{c}
\sum_{i=1}^n v_ix_i\geq D \\
x_i \in \{0,1\}, \forall{i}\in\{1,2,\dots,n\} 
\end{array}
\end{aligned}   
\end{equation}$$
However, we can also consider its relaxation:
$$\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\text{minimize } \quad & \sum_{i=1}^n p_ix_i \\
\text{subject to }\quad &
\begin{array}{c}
\sum_{i\in\{1,2,\dots,n\}\setminus A} v_i^Ax_i\geq D_A, \forall A\in S \\
0\leq x_i\leq 1 , \forall{i}\in\{1,2,\dots,n\} 
\end{array}
\end{aligned}   
\end{equation}$$
In this case, $S$ is the set of all subsets of questions whose total score is less than $D$. Also, $D_A=D-\sum_{i\in A}v_i$ and $v_i^A=\min\{v_i, D_A\}$.
I'm struggling to understand why these two formulations are equivalent and why the second LP satisfies the constraints of the problem.
Any assistance or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
EDIT

For example suppose we have 3 problems:

$(v_1=3, p_1=6)$
$(v_2=2, p_2=5)$
$(v_3=1.75, p_3=3.75)$

And the minimum score we need is $D=4.5$. We can pick questions in $2^3=8$ ways. Total score earned from each strategy is:

$\emptyset\rightarrow 0$
$\{1\}\rightarrow 3$
$\{2\}\rightarrow 2$
$\{3\}\rightarrow 1.75$
$\{1,2\}\rightarrow 5$
$\{1,3\}\rightarrow 4.75$
$\{2,3\}\rightarrow 3.75$
$\{1,2,3\}\rightarrow 6.75$

As you can see, only strategies in 5,6 and 8 have total score at least $D$. So the other subsets are elements of $S$.
Now for example consider $A=\{2,3\}\in S$. We have:
$$D_A=D-\sum_{i\in A}v_i=4.5-3.75=0.75$$
Then $v_1^A=\min\{0.75, 3\}=0.75$. So the constraint would be:
$$0.75x_1\geq 0.75$$
And we should do like this for other elements of $S$ as well.
EDIT

I think we should show constraints matrix of second formulation is totally unimodular. So we can conclude that the solution would be integer.

Cross-posted at https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/11876/why-this-ilp-and-lp-are-equivalent.

Let's consider a competition with $n$ questions. Each question has a price $p_i$ and a score $v_i$. To advance to the next round of the competition, we need to accumulate a minimum score of $D$. We can purchase a question, answer it, and earn its score. Assuming we can answer any question we buy, which subset of questions should we select to achieve a minimum score of $D$ while minimizing the total cost of the questions?
This problem can be formulated as an integer linear programming problem:
$$\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\text{minimize } \quad & \sum_{i=1}^n p_ix_i \\
\text{subject to }\quad &
\begin{array}{c}
\sum_{i=1}^n v_ix_i\geq D \\
x_i \in \{0,1\}, \forall{i}\in\{1,2,\dots,n\} 
\end{array}
\end{aligned}   
\end{equation}$$
However, we can also consider its relaxation:
$$\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\text{minimize } \quad & \sum_{i=1}^n p_ix_i \\
\text{subject to }\quad &
\begin{array}{c}
\sum_{i\in\{1,2,\dots,n\}\setminus A} v_i^Ax_i\geq D_A, \forall A\in S \\
0\leq x_i\leq 1 , \forall{i}\in\{1,2,\dots,n\} 
\end{array}
\end{aligned}   
\end{equation}$$
In this case, $S$ is the set of all subsets of questions whose total score is less than $D$. Also, $D_A=D-\sum_{i\in A}v_i$ and $v_i^A=\min\{v_i, D_A\}$.
I'm struggling to understand why these two formulations are equivalent and why the second LP satisfies the constraints of the problem.
Any assistance or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
EDIT

For example suppose we have 3 problems:

$(v_1=3, p_1=6)$
$(v_2=2, p_2=5)$
$(v_3=1.75, p_3=3.75)$

And the minimum score we need is $D=4.5$. We can pick questions in $2^3=8$ ways. Total score earned from each strategy is:

$\emptyset\rightarrow 0$
$\{1\}\rightarrow 3$
$\{2\}\rightarrow 2$
$\{3\}\rightarrow 1.75$
$\{1,2\}\rightarrow 5$
$\{1,3\}\rightarrow 4.75$
$\{2,3\}\rightarrow 3.75$
$\{1,2,3\}\rightarrow 6.75$

As you can see, only strategies in 5,6 and 8 have total score at least $D$. So the other subsets are elements of $S$.
Now for example consider $A=\{2,3\}\in S$. We have:
$$D_A=D-\sum_{i\in A}v_i=4.5-3.75=0.75$$
Then $v_1^A=\min\{0.75, 3\}=0.75$. So the constraint would be:
$$0.75x_1\geq 0.75$$
And we should do like this for other elements of $S$ as well.
EDIT

I think we should show constraints matrix of second formulation is totally unimodular. So we can conclude that the solution would be integer.

I think his-her problem is that, in the second formula, $x_{i}$ is not forced to be an integer. So, OP is wondering how he-she can be sure that, when the solver solves the second problem, it will always return 0 or 1 for the $x_{i}$.

Good point, I edited the response to incorporate feedback from your comment.

Thanks for you answer. I actually can't follow the third paragraph and I don't think it's correct. Also the second formulation is not an approximation. We should prove that the answer of the second formulation is the same as the first one. Is there a point you got and I don't?

@occasional: I would do research-investigation into what the necessary conditions are for the optimal solution of an LP to occur at the extreme points of the feasible solution. convexity is part of the condition but it's more involved than just that condition.
